# helper function calling from settimeout getting falied

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, lightning-apps

While, calling a helper function from inside of window.settimeout, i am getting the error as and function is not getting called

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   https://domain.com/_ui/common/request/servlet/JsLoggingServlet. 
>       No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. 
>       Origin 'https://domain.com' is therefore not allowed access.

```
init: function(component,event,helper) {

        var action = component.get("c.apexfunction");
         action.setParams({
             testId: testID
        });
        action.setCallback(this, function(response) {

            window.setTimeout(function() {                      
                helper.testFunction();
                }, 5000
            ); 

        }
},

testFunction : function(){
    alert('testFunction');

}
```

Comment: Also keep in mind that the setTimeout will break you out of the Aura lifecycle so if you need to modify any component or fire a server-side action in the setTimeout flow you'll want to wrap your code in $A.getCallback(). https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/js_cb_mod_ext_js.htm

Answer (score 3):

You have to Include `$A.enqueueAction(action)`

> ```
>             var action = component.get("c.apexfunction");
>              action.setParams({
>                  testId: testID
>             });
>             action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
>
>                 window.setTimeout(function() {
>
>
>                             helper.testFunction();
>
>
>                             }, 5000
>                         ); 
>
>             }); $A.enqueueAction(action);  },
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Hi guys thanks for your but unfortunately none worked well in my case. But, instead i used rerender which solved my issue.thanks again however for quick responses.